# Problems installing PHP CodeSniffer using Pear with Puppet

Tags: php, vagrant, ubuntu-12.04, puppet, pear

I'm using Vagrant and Puppet to set up a virtual machine. I'm encountering problems with PHP CodeSniffer being installed from Pear. The error I see is this:

```
==> default: err: /Stage[main]//Package[pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/pear upgrade -a pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer' returned 1: Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
==> default: downloading PHP_CodeSniffer-2.3.4.tgz ...
==> default: Starting to download PHP_CodeSniffer-2.3.4.tgz (473,411 bytes)
==> default: ................................................................................................done: 473,411 bytes
==> default: could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/php5-q1fasi/php5-5.3.10/pear-build-download/PHP_CodeSniffer-2.3.4.tgz"
==> default: Download of "pear/PHP_CodeSniffer" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
==> default: Error: cannot download "pear/PHP_CodeSniffer"
==> default: Download failed
==> default: upgrade failed
==> default:
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]//Vcsrepo[/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/WordPress]: Dependency Package[pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer] has failures: true
==> default: warning: /Stage[main]//Vcsrepo[/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/WordPress]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

I also can't manually install the package and see the same error. It seems to be related to an already reported problem whereby [Ubuntu can have problems unpackaging `tgz` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762141/pear-succeeded-but-it-is-not-a-valid-package#).

The relevant part of my Puppet file looks like this:

```
# Install PHP_CodeSniffer and the WordPress coding standard
package { 'pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer':
  ensure   => 'installed',
  provider => 'pear',
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can request the non-compressed version? Any other suggestions for resolving this problem much appreciated.

Comment: I'll note that this would be a question better suited to SuperUser or ServerFault, as it doesn't actually relate to programming itself.

Comment: *Infrastructure as Code* is programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you're missing `zip` or `zlib` extensions in PHP.