# how to install php_trader php ext in windows 10 with xampp

Tags: php, xampp, pear

Hey i am using xampp php 7.1

i am trying to install php_trader extension but

its showing me

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>       'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_trader.dll

which i have downloaded this from here

> https://pecl.php.net/package/trader/0.4.0/windows

How do i install correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than downloading the the extension from the website, you can install it using [PEAR](https://pear.php.net/), in xampp it should be present in the `/xampp/php/pear`, using,

Now open a command line and cd into `/xampp/php/`

try executing either one of the below commands. this will try to install the extension into the system.

```
pear install trader
```

pear have a bug related to the `.tar` archives, please find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762141/pear-succeeded-but-it-is-not-a-valid-package)

Comment: can you try windows cmd or powershell rather than bash ?